# cloudformation times out without initiating custom resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I've got a simple template testing communication with lambda called as custom resource. Something like:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "test": {
      "Type": "Custom::test",
      "Properties": {
        "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:lambda:xxxxx:mylambda",
        "Input": "some input"
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "debug": {
      "Description": "debug ami id",
      "Value": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "test", "output" ]}
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, this CFT sometimes works fine and sometimes times out at CREATE_IN_PROGRESS without reaching the "Resource creation initiated" stage (so without actually starting lambda). Is there any way I can decrease the failure rate? Right now it's close to 50% :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably has something to do with the actual *Lambda* code. It's important that you implement a proper exception catching mechanism. If something fails and it does not send the failure signal back to *CloudFormation*, the stack will wait forever (or until it times out).

It's worth noting that for the last 3 years that I've been using *Custom Resources* extensively, I've never had a *Lambda* not starting (at least in the regions I use: *us-east-1*, *ca-central-1*, *us-west-2*).

Comment: But it's the same lambda with the same input. And I see nothing in CloudWatch Logs until CF gets to the "Resource creation initiated" event. If lambda exited prematurely, I would at least see the "START" entry in the logs, right?

Comment: Is it a Lambda started inside a VPC? I've heard you can have problems like ENI exhaustion or if the chosen subnet has no route to the internet.

Comment: No, it's not running in a VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, so as Laurent suggested it **was** a problem with my lambda function. There was a condition under which it was exiting without saving the result to S3 (why the h* cloudformation cannot just read lambda output?). And "Resource creation initiated" seems to be rather indicator of data being saved to S3, not running the lambda. I corrected the exit condition, increased timeout and the function works like a charm.

What about the missing log entries you ask? Well, it was simply my mistake. As CloudWatch does not allow setting the log filter to future, or a dynamic "now", after every attempt I need to click the filter and change it to show the latest entries (one more point where aws could improve the user experience). I missed that detail and cloudwatch was simply not showing me the latest logs (silly me! sorry)